# Почему слеш в конце адресной строки ломает сайт, построенный по принципу единой точки входа?

Tags: php, apache, mvc, mod-rewrite

Реализация по принципу единой точки входа, содержимое адресной строки разбивается `$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` и результаты передаются в обработчики.

Адресная строка имеет следующий вид: `example.com/11/20`, где `11` - id пользователя, а `20` - id категории.

Записи в .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Возникла проблема с добавлением слеша в конец строки. Например, корректно работают адреса вида

```
example.com/11
example.com/11/
example.com/11/20
```

но начинаются проблемы, когда я пытаюсь добавить слеш (и дополнительную переменную) в конец строки:

```
example.com/11/20/
example.com/11/20/page3
```

В этом случае index-страница "теряет" стили css, библиотеки js и отображаемые изображения.

Кто-то может объяснить, почему добавление слеша ломает страницу, а главное, почему это происходит на определенном уровне вложенности (например, добавить слеш так - `example.com/11/` - еще можно, а так - `example.com/11/20/` - уже нельзя)? Это как-то можно исправить?

UPD.

Обработка всех `routes` происходит одинаково, т.е. *во всех случаях* подгружается `index.php` и переменной присваивается получаемое в результате разбора строки значение:

```
 if(!empty($routes[1])) {         //если это не главная страница всего сервиса
  if(intval($routes[1])) {       //если это страница пользователя, а не, например, поиск
   $user_id = intval($routes[1]) ;  

   if (empty($routes[2])) {   //если запрос главной страницы или категории (не контакты, не поиск ...)
    require "html/index.php";

   //some code

   require "html/index.php";
   $page = $routes[3];
```

Проблема частично решена тем, что в подгружаемом index.php в строках вида href="**..**/css/style.css" убрал переход на уровень вверх, т.е. заменил на href="/css/style.css" (без точек впереди). Написал *"частично решена"*, потому что теперь код работать-то работает и со слешем и без одинаково, но я не понимаю причин такого поведения и такой избирательности (за код прошу не пинать).

Comment: думаю тут нет телепатов, которые могут предположить что там у вас происходит в вашем коде. Из всего вашего описания, очевидно, что в `routes` получается на один элемент больше чем обычно. А вот как это влияет на логику дальнейшей обработки из текста вопроса не ясно. Изучайте код, смотрите что произойдет, когда в routes добавляется один пустой элемент.

Comment: где-то в routes не прописана или некорректно прописана обработка третьего по счету параметра URL

Comment: `В этом случае index-страница "теряет" стили css, библиотеки js и отображаемые изображения.` генерируйте для них абсолютные адреса, а не относительные.

Comment: CTRL + U нажмите, и посмотрите, что же там творится, может неправильный адрес к файлам генерируется...

Comment: @teran, обновил информацию в UPD.

Comment: @labris, все три параметра опрашиваются и из них извлекается значение. Во всех случаях идет подгрузка index.php

Comment: @Visman, так и поступил, таким образом все работает, но почему такое поведение кода?

Comment: @Руслан, там статика, все пути изначально записаны в index.php

Comment: ну, что я могу сказать... код в студию пожалуйста)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проблема только в статике, то необходимо указывать полный путь, так как все запросы идут к `./index.php`, а для браузера путь будет всегда вроде этого  `example.com/11/20/page3/css/style.css`

См. также [статью](http://imperacms.ru/docs/seo/url-slash-or-not), раздел "Вывод": поведение сервера при интерпретации слеша на конце (например, внутренний редирект на дефолтную начальную точку уровня - на файл index.html), это частный случай конкретной конфигурации сервера.

Comment: так и сделано, но остается вопрос: почему корректно отрабатывают запросы в адресной строке вида example.com/11/, но некорректно работают запросы вида example.com/11/20/ ? При том, что элементы массива $routes обрабатываются абсолютно одинаково - во всех случаях подгружается index.php.

Comment: Я же ответил, ДЛЯ БРАУЗЕРА путь будет не индекс, а УРЛ в адресной строке. Пути сервера и браузера это разные вещи. Корень браузера это /, соответственно, поднимаясь на уровень вверх из /11/ попадаете в корень, а из /11/20/ в /11/